# how to find the center/x,y coordinate of an image in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

So I have a UIWebView which I have added a touch gesture in it, and I would like to find the x,y origin coordinates of an image tapped in the web view or if possible the center of the image in x y coordinates in the web view. The code I have is:

```
- (CGPoint) topLeftPointsForImage:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint pt = [sender locationInView:self];
    NSString * offsetTop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).offsetTop", pt.x, pt.y
                          ];

    NSString * offsetLeft = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).offsetLeft", pt.x, pt.y
                      ];

    NSString * scrollTop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).parentNode.scrollTop", pt.x, pt.y
                              ];

    NSString * scrollLeft = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).parentNode.scrollLeft", pt.x, pt.y
                             ];


    float x = [[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:offsetTop] floatValue] - [[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scrollTop] floatValue];
    float y = [[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:offsetLeft] floatValue] - [[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scrollLeft] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"Coor height is %f with coor width is %f", x, y);

    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(x, y);
    return point;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to give me a correct value. I am not a javascript master, so looking for some advice for this.

Comment: What value do you receive? It might be the case that you need to convert the results coming out from the JS code to strings using: document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).offsetTop.toString()

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery in your html page, then you may try to use :

```
NSString * offsetTop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$(document).elementFromPoint(%f, %f).offsetTop;", pt.x, pt.y
                      ];
```

also note the semi-colon at the end of the statement.  All Javascript statements must be valid and properly terminated, just like inside a html page.

If you are injecting a library, you have to properly put into a function class with namespaces, as follows:

```
"(function () {return "your data";}) ();"
```